# Rabbitmq authentication failure

Tags: authentication, erlang, rabbitmq

I try to connect with erlang amqp client to rabbitmq server.

I made connection params:

```
AMQP_Param = #amqp_params_network{
            host = <<"localhost">>,
                username = <<"guest">>
                password = <<"123456">>,
                port = 5672
                virtual_host = test_virtual_host
                heartbeat = 5
            },
```

Now i run rabbitmq server and try to connect to it:

```
amqp_connection:start(AMQP_Param)
```

But i got error:

```
{error,auth_failure}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the default guest user for RabbitMQ? If so, I think the password should be guest.